# TesseractNotFound Error: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path

Tags: python, tesseract

I installed `tesseract` using `homebrew` on mac and I installed `pytesseract` as well. But I still got the error that says this:

```
TesseractNotFound Error: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

**EDIT**

Commands I used to install

```
# pytesseract
pip install pytesseract

# tesseract
brew install tesseract
```

I adde this line of code:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/share/tessdata/"
```

But I got this error message:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/share/tessdata/'
```

How can I allow access?

Comment: Can you please provide more informations, such as the versions of python, tesseract, pytesseract, as well as the commands you have used to install all of these. Always keep in mind that we are trying to solve the problem with the information you are giving us ;)

Answer (score 0):

- You have to also download Tesseract OCR

You can download it from here:
https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Downloads.html

After installation make sure to add installation to your script. if your installation path is

```
"C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR"
```

set the OCR path like this in your python script `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"`

This will work.

Comment: But I'm not using Windows

Comment: You can get OCR from here based on your OS: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html

Comment: I got another issue. Please help me out

Comment: What's that issue?